# Batch file: How to get variable's value using variable's name already stored in a string

Tags: string, variables, batch-file, command-prompt

1)  Quick example:

```
set a="Hello"
set d="a"
```

Now, how do I get the value of "a" using (the value of) variable `d`?  For example, the variable name could have been entered by a user using a prompt, or the name of the variable could have been sent to a function.

None of these ideas work:

```
set e=%%d%%

set e=%%%d%%%

set e=set e=%%d%%
%e%
```

After an hour of brainstorming and Googling, I have come up with this, but it seems too complicated and clumsy - is there really no other/easier way?:

```
set a="Hello"
set b="Good day"
set c="Good night"

set /p d="Give me a variable name"

call :GetVarVal %%%d%%% "e"

REM This now gives the correct value:
echo %e%

goto :eof

:GetVarVal
  set "%~2=%~1"
goto :eof
```

2)  Also, sort of similar, is there a better way to do this (ideally without a custom function):

```
set a="C:\Users\Blah\Documents\MP4Box\MP4Box.exe"

call :get_drive_and_path a

echo %b%

goto :eof

:get_drive_and_path
  set b=%~dp1
goto :eof
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

example without `delayed expansion` (preserves exclamation marks):

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "a=Hello!"
set "d=a"
call echo %%%d%%%
```

---

output:

```
Hello!
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think this is the closest answer to what I was hoping for.  Batch scripts are weird.

Comment: This is the method I have used before. Usually as `call set myvar=%%%othervar%%%` to get a value by name

Answer (score 7):

If I understood you correctly, the trick called "delayed expansion" should work:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET a=Hello
SET b=a
ECHO This is the value of a: !%b%!
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Check how it works [here](http://batcheero.blogspot.se/2007/06/how-to-enabledelayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Thanks!  I went with Endoro's answer because it was more what I was looking for and apparently will preserve exclamation marks - which I do need it to cope with.  But it's good to know about the delayed expansion method too.

Answer (score 3):

Part 2

```
set file="C:\Users\Blah\Documents\MP4Box\MP4Box.exe"
for %%a in (%file%) do echo %%~dpa
```

Comment: Thanks.  Did not think of that; avoids the subroutine :)

Answer (score 0):

its just easy:
as you type e.g.

```
SET VarName=VarValue
```

Then the SET-function gets given a string looking like "VarName=VarValue" - it does not matter whether you use the marks there or not, the following commands do the same:

```
SET VarName=VarValue
SET "VarName=VarValue"
```

so now reflecting, what tools we have to build a string, we come up to the idea to use this:

```
SET "Name=VarName"
SET "%VarName%=VarValue"
Echo %Varname%
```

Better late than never - have a good time